# Pass data from Component into Root

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Assume this Component :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
          return {
              items: [
                  { message: 'Test 1' },
                  { message: 'Test 2' },
                  { message: 'Test 3' },
              ]
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is my `app.js` :

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Now, I need to print all `items` in example Component like so :

```
<ul id="example-2">
   <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
       @{{ index }} - @{{ item.message }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

It returns me following error :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "items" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.  (found in )

**The Main Question Is :**

How do I pass data from a child component into Root ?

Any helps would be great appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the parent to be able to specify how the child should lay out the data essentially? As in, the parent should specify the `panel-body` of your component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways in which you can have *non parent-child* (direct relationship) communication.

1. Emit an event from the child component and then emit the value from the receiving parent further up until the root receives the value. (Don't use this)
2. Use an [event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication), this is the answer you are looking for if your application is small sized.
3. Use vuex, this is the answer you are looking for if your application will have more use of component states/is a large scale application.

---

**Example**

```
// assuming your component
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data() {
      return {
          items: [
              { message: 'Test 1' },
              { message: 'Test 2' },
              { message: 'Test 3' },
          ]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
        this.setItemsToStore(this.items)
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        'setItemsToStore': 'SET_ITEMS_TO_STORE'
      })
    }
}
```

Then wire up `vuex` in main.js.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { store } from './path/to/store'
import App from './path/to/App'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Setup a modular vuex store like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import itemStore from './modules/itemStore'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    itemStore
  }
})
```

and finally your itemStore can look like:

```
const state = {
  ITEMS: []
}

const getters = {
  GET_ITEMS: (state) => {
    return state.ITEMS
  }
}

const mutations = {
  MUTATE_ITEMS: (state, payload) => {
    state.ITEMS = payload
  }
}

const actions = {
  SET_ITEMS_TO_STORE: ({commit}, payload) => {
    commit('MUTATE_ITEMS', payload)
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

After this setup, your `app.js` can use it like:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      'items': 'GET_ITEMS'
    })
  }
});
```

---

**Example 2**

```
//bus.js

export new Vue()
```

This is an empty vue instance which will be used throughout the application.

```
// your assumed component
import eventBus from 'path/to/bus.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
     items: [
          { message: 'Test 1' },
          { message: 'Test 2' },
          { message: 'Test 3' },
       ]
     }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
    eventBus.$emit('items-evt', this.items)
  }
}
```

Here, you just emit an event when your component is mounted.

```
// app.vue
import eventBus from 'path/to/bus.js'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    eventBus.$on('items-evt', (items) => {
      this.items = items
    })
  }
});
```

To listen on the app component the moment it is created.

Comment: Thank you. I read [vuex](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vue.js/3430/vuex#t=201703211059273183281) link, But I still don't what to do in my case! :(

Comment: Wow! How difficult! :(

Comment: It will be worth it, if your application has a lot of inter-component communication. Else, use eventBus, thats much more simpler.

Comment: I would appreciate you If you give me an `eventBus` example.

Comment: @HamedKamrava I added an example for eventBus